# How to automatically open my app when a condition is met?

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am working on a streaming app between android device and a Pi using Gstreamer. I need a way to automatically launch the app ,so the user can accept the call, when a pipeline is active. 
Is it this possible? or any other method to notify the user about the call.

Comment: please explain the problem more. How is the pipeline running? Who invokes the pipeline? On what condition, the app needs to be launched ? You can use the concept of messages/events/signals to lauch the app appropriately.

Comment: The pipeline on the android is always listening. The Pi calls the android device by choosing the corresponding IP address, then the stream begins. Ideally, I want the app to launch when my pipeline state changes to PLAYING.
Could you please tell me more about this events/signals.

Comment: poll for the state of pipeline, and then launch the app. that is one way of doing it,

Comment: excuse my limited knowledge in android, I am just a beginner. could you explain more. and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have access to the source code, use the API `get_state()` to obtain the state of the pipeline. Here is the link, that explains the Gstreamer States and how to obtain them in detail:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/states.html#getting-the-state-of-elements